# Polymorphic Set with polymorphic compare from functor-based Set

Tags: set, ocaml

Jane Street Core has a very handy `'a Core.Set.Poly.t` which is a polymorphic set based on polymorphic `Pervasives.compare`.

For example, this set has a `map` function that maps `'a -> 'b`. For comparison standard OCaml set is functor-based and produces a monomorphic set which `map` function maps `'a -> 'a`.

Is there a convenient way to produce or emulate such "Poly" set using only standard library, without rolling out your own implementation from scratch?

Answer (score 3):

The stdlib `Set` cannot be polymorphic, as its type constructor doesn't have any arguments. However, you can express `map` from arbitrary set to arbitrary set with a functor:

```
module MapSet (S1:Set.S) (S2:Set.S) = struct
  let map f a = S1.fold (fun elt set -> S2.add (f elt) set) a S2.empty
end
```

The usage:

```
module IntSet = Set.Make (struct type t = int let compare = compare end)
module StringSet = Set.Make (String)

module MapSI = MapSet (StringSet) (IntSet)

# IntSet.elements (MapSI.map String.length (StringSet.of_list ["a"; "zonk"; "blart"]));;
- : IntSet.elt list = [1; 4; 5]
```

As you can see, it is straightforward but verbose and 'namey'.

Another alternative is to use an `('a, unit) Hashtbl` as a mutable set, which will use polymorphic equality under the hood (with all the usual drawbacks). You can easily implement your own `map` operation:

```
let map_keys f tbl =
  let new_tbl = Hashtbl.create (Hashtbl.length tbl) in
  Hashtbl.iter (fun k v -> Hashtbl.replace new_tbl (f k) v) tbl;
  new_tbl
```

Be mindful that `Hashtbl` does not provide the worst case guarantees that `Set` does, or efficient union/diff/intersection operations.

Comment: nice solution. One question : what do you mean by 'Hashtbl does not provide the worst case guarantees that Set does' ?

Comment: For `Set`, `mem`, `add`, etc are logarithmic in the size of the set. `Hashtbl`'s worst case is O(n), although it is unlikely to occur.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof of concept that uses Marshal and Set from the standard library. The argument is that it's not built from scratch because it's just a thin layer on top of Set.

```
module PSet = Set.Make(struct type t = bytes let compare = compare end)

module type POLYSET = sig
    type 'a t
    val empty : 'a t
    val mem : 'a -> 'a t -> bool
    val add : 'a -> 'a t -> 'a t
    val fold : ('a -> 'b -> 'b) -> 'a t -> 'b -> 'b
    val map : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a t -> 'b t
end

module PolySet : POLYSET = struct
    type 'a t = PSet.t
    let wrap x = Marshal.to_bytes x []
    let unwrap b = Marshal.from_bytes b 0
    let empty = PSet.empty
    let mem elt set =
        PSet.mem (wrap elt) set
    let add elt set =
        PSet.add (wrap elt) set
    let fold f set init =
        PSet.fold (fun bytes acc -> f (unwrap bytes) acc) set init
    let map f set =
        fold (fun elt bset -> add (f elt) bset) set empty
end
```

It works for me:

```
# module P = Sm.PolySet;;
module P = Sm.PolySet
# let x = P.add 14 (P.add 88 P.empty);;
val x : int P.t = <abstr>
# P.mem 14 x;;
- : bool = true
# P.mem 15 x;;
- : bool = false
# P.mem "abc" x;;
Error: This expression has type int P.t = int Sm.PolySet.t
       but an expression was expected of type
         string P.t = string Sm.PolySet.t
       Type int is not compatible with type string
# P.fold (fun x l -> x :: l) x [];;
- : int list = [88; 14]
# let y = P.map float_of_int x;;
val y : float P.t = <abstr>
# P.fold (fun x l -> x :: l) y [];;
- : float list = [88.; 14.]
```

**Update**

In fairness I should point out that the convenience of this solution comes at a cost. The Marshal module is going to copy (and hance traverse) your set elements for each operation.

Comment: This is deliciously disgusting. :)

Comment: Personally I voted for your answer. But I can't resist a challenge.